# Nine is the limit

Tags: riddle, word

> My first is in a bank,
>   My second is an evergreen,
>   My third is for your benefit
>   My fourth is in a store,
>   My fifth is identical,
>   If you've found the pattern
>   What is my sixth?

Those definitions might be a bit broad, but there is only one answer that follows the pattern.
If needed, I will add more clues.

---

> This has nothing to do with computer. Each line refers to one word. Words may or may not be in the same semantic field but that's not what is important.

---

> As you, fellow puzzlers, keep to try to make sense of this riddle as a whole, I need to tell you that each definition gives a word but those words are not in the same semantic field nor express the same idea.

---

I hope this one won't be an easy giveaway

> My first is cautious,
>  My second is wise,
>  My third is wine,
>  My fourth happens in the garage,
>  My fifth is unchanged
>  Now you should have a better grasp on the pattern
>  So what is my sixth?

Comment: may be sixth is limit?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati nope, nine is the limit

Comment: I don't think the keyboard answers are on track because I don't see how "Nine is the limit" fits into that.

Comment: Part of me wants to say Star Wars movies, which might work because there are plans for a total of nine but only six have actually been released so far. The only problem is that as far as I can tell, none of the episodes really fit the clues except Attack of the Clones (my fifth is identical). Perhaps it's another film or book series?

Comment: @aleppke I am afraid not

Comment: @aleppke I had the same thought! :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your sixth is

> sane

because

> each word is an iteration of the pattern S A _ E

My first is in a bank,  My first is cautious

> safe

My second is an evergreen,  My second is wise

> sage

My third is for your benefit, My third is wine

> sake

My fourth is in a store,    My fourth happens in the garage

> sale

My fifth is identical,  My fifth is unchanged

> same

Nine is the limit because

> there are only three other words that fit the pattern: sate, save, and Saxe

Comment: That was a big giveaway :) I should update my question because with Saxe, it adds a tenth item in the list. I thought of S.A.S.E

Comment: I figured you skipped that one because it's an acronym :)

Comment: This is a really nice, compact, well-made puzzle!  You really had me scratching my head.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed it

Comment: Wow, well done, with the giveaway I started playing with words, but well done master dennis.

Answer (score 10):

Looking outside of our narrow box

> Mercury, mercury is also a metal, metal in banks (gold, silver)

So next would be

> Venus, well its always yellowish according to the internet but I think of it as greeny-blue, ever green.

Lets roll with it

> Earth, I mean I think it is useful to us, even if we aren't useful to it.

4.

> Mars, MARS BARS! candy is in a store

5

> Jupiter, which is a bit stupider... but according to a website aimed at 5th graders: The atmospheres of Saturn and Jupiter are almost identical

And what is 5 identical to?

> Saturn, the 6th planet from the sun.

EDIT:

> woops forgot to say 9 is the limit because VIVA LA PLUTO!

Comment: >! http://www.kidsastronomy.com/academy/lesson210_assignment1_4.htm

Comment: Good thinking, but that's not the answer

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I know the full answer, but I feel like I'm on to the method of getting the answer. Perhaps someone could finish what I started here:

> Each line refers to one word, as stated, but each word when said aloud is also a letter. So the full thing is a nine letter word (since nine is the limit) and the answer to the puzzle is the 6th letter of said word.

E.g.

> Q in most banks a QUEUE could be found

---

> U one type of evergreen is the YEW

---

> O it is certainly in your benefit for me to OWE you something

---

> The fourth and fifth is where I get stuck. The fact that the fifth is identical implies that the fifth letter is the same as the fourth letter. First, I tried looking for all 9 letter words starting with quo. However, none have the 4th and 5th letter identical.

Since that didn't work, let's try again:

> G as in grand. Any bank that doesn't have that much money is a pretty poor bank.

---

> U Let's stick with YEW since vowels are hard to come by and so do evergreens.

---

> T Many believe TEA to be beneficial to their health.

---

> Back where we started. QUEUEs definitely are in stores, but count for me the number of words with qq in it. Here's a hint, there aren't any. :) But what 9 letter words start with GUT and then have 2 of the same letter... Again the answer is none. So, at least one of my first three in each idea are incorrect.

So, I don't have the full answer. Who can help me? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Good try, but you're not on the right track

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess

> Is it the symbols on the keyboard along the numbers $ ^% ^ & * (

My first is in a bank,

> $- Dollar sign/Money

My second is an evergreen,

> % -Percentages have been used always as an ideal measure of performance

My third is for your benefit

> ^ - Up arrows are often used for marking text and for easier readability

My fourth is in a store,

> & -Don't know how this connects. Maybe refers to shops often being named "Mom & Pops"

My fifth is identical,

> * - Maybe a reference to it being a symmetric symbol. Or could be because the * symbol is used to match repeating or identical patterns (thanks Samthere)

If you've found the pattern
What is my sixth?

> Is it the symbol (

Comment: Shouldn'y it be the symbol '('?

Comment: You changes your answer and now it is wrong. By your logic, * should be fifth, not (

Comment: * could be identical because it's often used as a wildcard in computing, matching any other patter.

Comment: @Samthere: yeah i thought so too.

Comment: Good thinking but that's not it

Answer (score 1):

Going by valuable_asset@ solution:

My first is in a bank,

> $ (Dollars)

My second is an evergreen,

> #(Could be Hashish)

My third is for your benefit

> @ (Email)

My fourth is in a store,

> ! (Not sure, could be mark or a part of the name)

My fifth is identical,

> ~ (Symbol of similar to)

If you've found the pattern

> Pattern is all symbols going from 4,3,2,1,~,` or if nine is the limit it could be 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ~, -, *, / (Going backwards and including numlock).

What is my sixth?

> ` or -

Comment: Good thinking but that's not it

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of @valuable_asset and @theplace, perhaps 2 is:

> Num lock, as I don't know many people who turn it off

and 3 might be:

> Backspace, which is there for correcting our mistakes

4.

> $ again

Meaning 5. is

> Num lock (identical to 2)

And 6. would be

> backspace again.

Comment: Sorry that's not it

Answer (score 1):

could it be

> money

My first is in a bank,

> Money is in the bank

My second is an evergreen,

> US dollars are green

My third is for your benefit

> Everyone likes having money

My fourth is in a store,

> you by stuff at stores with money

My fifth is identical,

> Abraham Lincoln is on the five dollar bill and one cent coin

If you've found the pattern
What is my sixth?

> not sure what the sixth would be, possibly the $100 dollar bill

Nine is the limit,

> could refer to the people on the bills and coins not repeated and found in general circulation. i.e. not the $1 coin or $500/$2 bill

---

My other idea could be

> the Nine planetary limits but I can't figure out how to relate the clues

Comment: Nope, that's not it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be:

> Spades/spade, as in the suit in playing cards.

---

My first is in a bank

> Diamonds, they can be kept in banks.

My second is an evergreen

> Clubs, since the clover plant is evergreen.

My third is for your benefit

> Hearts, as you would die without one (pretty big benefit)!

My fourth is in a store,

> Spades, they are sold in stores (and it's the only suit left...)

My fifth is identical,

> Identical to what? This one's throwing me off -- but I'll go with the jokers (since there are two).

If you've found the pattern

What is my sixth?

> ...so I assume that the pattern turns around and goes back to spades here.

Comment: Interesting idea but I don't see how it fits with "Nine is the limit".

Comment: @aleppke: Good point. My initial thought was that if the pattern restarted/turned around at #5 and ended where it began it would make nine in total, but by that logic it could continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Is it anyway related to

> nine Planets, since Nine is a limit.

My Sixth is

> Saturn.

To start with,

My First is in bank

> Mercury - Mercury payment systems

My second is an evergreen

> Venus - Venus glows green

My third is for your benefit

> Earth - is for our benefit

My fourth is in a store

> Mars - Chocolate

My fifth is identical

> Jupiter - atmospheres of Saturn and Jupiter are almost identical

Comment: Going hamateur beat you to this idea, and apparently it's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to PuzzlingSE and thank you for contributing. However, this appears to be a duplicate of another answer, and hence, may be removed. In the future, kindly review other answers before posting your own. Happy puzzling!