# Nine is the limit... again

Tags: riddle, word

As you liked [Nine is the limit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17565/nine-is-the-limit), I decided to make you an other one.

> My first is a harvester,
>   My second is a payment,
>   My third comes with a surprise,
>   My fourth is a soldier,
>   My fifth comes with a maiden,
>   If you've found the pattern
>   What is my sixth?

Those definitions might be a bit broad, but there is only one answer that follows the pattern.
If needed, I will add more clues.

Comment: driving me crazy already. midnight here. i've gotta sleep!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first is a harvester,

> Bee

My second is a payment,

> Fee

My third comes with a surprise,

> Gee

My fourth is a soldier,

> Lee (General Lee)

My fifth comes with a maiden,

> Nee (maiden name)

If you've found the pattern
What is my sixth?

> Pee

Also, seven through nine are:

> See, Tee, Wee

Comment: Dee and Zee are also valid words.

Comment: nice find. i almost had it! i saw fee as a synonym for payment, but before i could try it, i got sidetracked down another path.